# Mother aggression towards puppy and impact to the puppy

Tags: dogs, behavior, aggression, psychology

I'm doing some research into the way mother's aggression (not normal levels of discipline) can affect a puppy as it grows and becomes an adult.

Specifically, focusing on long term behaviour.

Would anyone be able to refer me to online articles - academic if possible - on the subject?